# Python dictionary has_key

Tags: python, dictionary

```py
x1={0:1,2:3,4:5}
x2={1:6, 3:8, 5:40, 7:10}

x2 = dict([(k, v) for (k, v) in x2.items() if x1.has_key(v)])
```

I except the answer to be

```
x2={1:6, 3:8, 5:40}
```

but instead I get a syntax error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try this, ```x2 = dict([(k, v) for (k, v) in x2.items() if x1.get(k)])```

Comment: You will get an `AttributeError` not `SyntaxError` which is self-explanatory.

Comment: @Austin only on Python3, which OP has not specified.

Comment: @AdamSmith: Yes, but in Python 2 there will be no errors.

Comment: @Austin when the choice is between "OP is describing a different error than what is presented" and "OP is describing an error where none exists," one should err on the side of asking "Please provide more details" rather than guessing :)

Comment: @Sushanth I tried, I don't get attribute error anymore but the returned dictionary is empty

Comment: Python version is 3.7

Comment: @AfiaR.S. I think you mean 2.7. if you wrote that code in 3.7 you would get an AttributeError (`dict` has no `has_key` method)

Comment: @AdamSmith yes, you are correct it was Attribute error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a *bunch* of conflating errors here.

First of all, a stack trace would show where the SyntaxError is, but you haven't included one in your posted code.

Second of all, you appear to want all the key-value pairs in `x2` where the *value* appears in `x1`, not where the `key` appears in `x1`. That's harder, since `x1` is not indexed by its values (obviously).

You could create such a set first:

```py
x1_values = set(v for _, v in x1.items())
```

then use that as your selector

```py
result = dict([(k, v) for k, v in x2.items() if v in x1_values])
```

Alternatively you could iterate over `x1` and return the key-value pair in `x2` if it exists.

```py
result = dict([(v, x2[v]) for _, v in x1.items() if v in x2)
```

Note that in all my code snippets, I write `key in dictionary` rather than `dictionary.has_key(key)`. The `dict.has_key` method is not supported in Python3, and speaking of which....

---

...it appears that you're writing code for a very old version of Python. Python2 is no longer supported, and you should update to the now decade-old Python3 ASAP. This code there looks like:

```py
x1_values = {v for _, v in x1.items()}
result = {k: v for k, v in x2.items() if v in x1_values}
```